# Automatic generate mipmap for cubemap in d3d11

Tags: c++, texture-mapping, direct3d11

Recently I have an issue with creating mipmaps for cube maps in d3d11. The idea letting the DirectX framework generate the images for each lod for each plane in the cube map, but it seems acts like I should create manually for them.

What is the correct way to generate mips for textures? Do I have to generate them on my own, or is there a way to make d3d to do them?

This is the way I'm creating textures:

```
void TextureCube::Initialize(Renderer & device, CubemapRef cubemap)
{
    HRESULT result;

    BitmapRef bitmap = cubemap->GetPosX(); //assume that everything is equal there
    int ch = bitmap->GetCh();
    DXGI_FORMAT fmt = bitmapformats[ch % 4];

    m_format = fmt;

    m_w = cubemap->GetPosX()->GetX();
    m_h = cubemap->GetPosX()->GetY();
    m_ch = (m_ch == 3) ? 4 : ch; // if bitmap has 3 component per pixel, we'll force it to 4 and convert it before creating initial data
    m_chW = 1;


    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));
    textureDesc.Width = m_w;
    textureDesc.Height = m_h;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 0;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 6;
    textureDesc.Format = m_format;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE| D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE | D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;

    // --- setup inital data 
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA pData[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        void *inData = cubemap->GetBitmap(i)->GetData();
        void *outData = inData;
        if (cubemap->GetBitmap(i)->GetCh() == 3) {
            outData = new unsigned int[m_w * m_h];
            CopyChannel3To4(inData, outData, m_w, m_h);
        }
        pData[i].pSysMem = outData;
        pData[i].SysMemPitch = m_w * 4;
        pData[i].SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    }

    ID3D11Texture2D *ppTex = nullptr;
    result = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, pData, &ppTex);

    // cleanup converted data 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        if (pData[i].pSysMem != cubemap->GetBitmap(i)->GetData())
            delete pData[i].pSysMem;

    if (FAILED(result)) 
        throw EX_HRESULT(TextureCreateException, result);

    m_pTexture = ppTex;

    // --- srv
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&shaderResourceViewDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = m_format;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;

    shaderResourceViewDesc.TextureCube.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.TextureCube.MipLevels = -1;

    result = device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_pTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &m_pResourceView);

    if (FAILED(result)) 
        throw EX_HRESULT(TextureCreateException, result);

}
```

Comment: You should pass the pointer to ID3D11ShaderResourceView to D3D11DeviceContext::GenerateMips: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476426(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, and as it turned out since, I have to set `textureDesc.MipLevels` to `1` instead of 0, to avoid `CreateTexture2D` to looking for mip levels in the bitmap data. I call `GenerateMips` after RTV is created, but what is unclear is how should I setup `shaderResourceViewDesc` and/or `textureDesc` to generate it?

Comment: You need to check that autogen mipmaps generation is supported at runtime since the driver is free to not do it in some cases--in which case ``GenerateMips`` silently fails. They are also free to do a really poor quality job, so YMMV. I really only use autogen mips with 2D textures as shown in [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/WICTextureLoader.cpp), otherwise I'd recommend generating them offline (see [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex)).